# append input checkbox in jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, append

I have input checkbox namely select all. I added the checkbox from jquery end. if user click on select all rest of the option will be checked. but I'm getting error when click on select all. here I'm attaching the code.

```
$('#multiple_msisdn').append(
'<label class="exp" style="margin-bottom: 5px; display: inline-block;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="exp" onclick="$(input[name=msisdn\\[\\]])
 .attr(checked, this.checked)">-- Select All -- </label>');
```

> error: uncaught syntaxError.
>
> error generated here `$(input[name=msisdn\[\]]).attr(checked,> this.checked)`

Comment: can you show code where all the inputs wit name msisdn is!

Comment: <div id="multiple_msisdn" style="display: inline-block;"><label class="exp" style="margin-bottom: 5px; display: inline-block;"><input type="checkbox" class="exp" onclick="$(input[name=msisdn\[\]]).attr(checked, this.checked)"> -- Select All -- </label><label class="exp"><input type="checkbox" class="exp" name="msisdn[]" value="1">&nbsp;ABC [xxxxxxxx]</label><br><label class="exp"><input type="checkbox" class="exp" name="msisdn[]" value="18">&nbsp;ABC [xxxxxx]</label><br></div>

Comment: This is not readable. please put this in your question in proper format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#multiple_msisdn').append('<label class="exp" style="margin-bottom: 5px; display: inline-block;"><input type="checkbox" class="exp SelectAll"> -- Select All -- </label>').append('<br><label class="exp" style="margin-bottom: 5px; display: inline-block;"><input type="checkbox" class="exp" name="msisdn[]"> -- 1 -- </label>').append('<br><label class="exp" style="margin-bottom: 5px; display: inline-block;"><input type="checkbox" class="exp" name="msisdn[]"> -- 2 -- </label>');

$(document).on("click",".SelectAll",function(){
  $("input[name='msisdn[]']").prop('checked',$(this).is(':checked'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="multiple_msisdn"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is because you are writing javascript code inline & not escaping the characters.

Now better way to implement is use jquery to have handler functions.
Check out the example below. Select All selects/unselects All as well as if user changes checkboxes individually the select all reflects correct state.
Try selecting all checkboxes individually & select all would also be checked & vice versa.

```js
$(function() {

  //handler for selectall change
  $('#selectAll').change(function() {
    $("input[name='msisdn[]']").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'))
  })

  //handler for all checkboxes to refect selectAll status
  $("input[name='msisdn[]']").change(function() {
    $("#selectAll").prop('checked', true)
    $("input[name='msisdn[]']").each(function() {
      if (!$(this).prop('checked')){
        $("#selectAll").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
        return;
      }
    })
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="multiple_msisdn">
  <label class="exp">
<input type="checkbox" class="exp" id="selectAll"> -- Select All -- </label>
  <label class="exp">
<input type="checkbox" class="exp" name="msisdn[]" value="1">&nbsp;ABC [xxxxxxxx]</label>
  <label class="exp">
 <input type="checkbox" class="exp" name="msisdn[]" value="18">&nbsp;ABC [xxxxxx]</label>
</div>
```